# calling apex method without a return value from controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I am trying to call an apex method through a controller. I have read somewhere the apex methods without any return should be prefixed with get. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. It says cant find the method.
here is the apex:

```
        for (Opportunity opp : [Select Id, Name, StageName from Opportunity]) {
        opp.StageName = 'Won';
        update opp;
    }
```

Here is the call from the controller:

```
changeStageBackWon : function(component, event, helper) {
    var updateOpportunityStageBackWon = component.get("c.getMoveOppBackWon");
    //updateOpportunityStageBackWon.setParams({ opps : component.get("v.opportunityData") });
    updateOpportunityStageBackWon.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();            
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
        }            
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(updateOpportunityStageBackWon); 
}
```

Comment: How is your method declared in Apex?

Comment: *I have read somewhere the apex methods without any return should be prefixed with get.* This generalization makes no sense.

Comment: Hey Adrian, this was the msg that I got from dev console "non static auraenabled methods must be named with a prefix 'get'" when i ran my code initially. At that time i didn't have static included in my declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all Apex methods, that are not returning something back, we will need to declare them as `void`. So you need to do something like this:

```
public static void theVoidMethod(){

// Your code here 

}
```

or

```
public void theVoidMethod2(){

    // Your code here 

    }
```

[**Check this link to learn more about Apex methods.**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm)

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I was doing the same, for some reason it was not working then, but now its working. I do the coding on developer console, once you save , it takes a while to see that reflected on the browser. Not sure as of now how to fix that.